# Laravel CRUD Axios Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Im creating my first CRUD in Vue/Laravel and now I'm trying to send a create to my backend application, this is my code:

Frontend:

```
async addDespesa() {
  let uri = "api/despesas/create";
  const response = await axios.get(uri, this.despesa).then((response) => {
    this.$router.push({ name: "despesas" });
  });
},
```

Backend:

```
public function create()
{
    //
}
```

Errors in inspect on Browser:

```
>[vue-router] Route with name 'despesas' does not exist 

>Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/".
    at createRouterError 
at createNavigationDuplicatedError
at HashHistory.confirmTransition
at HashHistory.transitionTo
at eval
at HashHistory.push
at new Promise
 at VueRouter.push
at eval
```

Comment: Please post your back-end code as well :)

Comment: what methods are allowed for the `api/despesas/create` endpoint? is `POST` one of them

Comment: The endpoint was wrong. I changed post for get and another error appears. I edit the post with all my frontend, backend and error code

Comment: The error means you haven't defined a route named 'despesas'.  Check the route definition has the `name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend seems fine, the problem is in the `.then` part of your Axios call:

```
this.$router.push({ name: "despesas" });
```

You should check your frontend routes (probably in a file called `routes.js`) and make sure you have a route named `despesas`. So something like this:

```
let routes = [
    {
        'path': '/path/to/despesas',
        'name': 'despesas',
        component: require('./path/to/despesas-component').default
    },
    
    ...

    other routes
];
```